# How to find the smallest variance that can be achieved by an unbiased estimator?

Tags: statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ denote a random sample from the PDF

$$f_{\varphi}(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \varphi x^{\varphi - 1} &\text{if}\, 0 < x < 1, \varphi > 0\\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to find the smallest variance that can be achieved by an unbiased estimator of $\varphi$. However, I've never had to find such a thing. How does one calculate this?

Comment: Maybe this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound).

Comment: @Snoop Ahh, ok, that's something I've heard of. The context mentions the "Fisher information number" too, so I think this is it. Do you happen to know how this works for a function like $f_{\varphi}(x)$?

Comment: The derivative of the log-lihelihood function is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}\ln(\varphi x^{\varphi-1})=\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}(\ln(\varphi)+\ln(x)(\varphi-1))=\frac{1}{\varphi}+\ln(x)$$
So the Fisher information is ultimately equal to
$$\mathcal{I}(\varphi)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}\ln(\varphi x^{\varphi-1})\right)^2\varphi x^{\varphi-1}dx=\frac{1}{\varphi^2}$$
If $\hat{\varphi}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\varphi$, the lower bound on the estimator variance is
$$\mathbb{V}(\hat{\varphi})\geq \varphi^2$$

Answer (score 1):

First observe that your density belongs to the exponential family. This assure that the needed regular conditions to apply Cramér Rao inequality are satisfied.

Thus, applying CR inequality we have that, for any unbiased estimator $T$ for $\varphi$

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{1}{-n\mathbb{E}\left\{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2}\log f(x;\varphi)  \right\}}$$

- $\log f(x,\varphi)=\log \varphi+(\varphi-1)\log x$
- $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2}\log f(x;\varphi)  =-\frac{1}{\varphi^2}$

Thus

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{\varphi^2}{n}$$